# Pointer of a pointer as function argument

Tags: c, function, pointers, arguments

```
   typedef struct rilevamenti {
   char     idStazione[4];
   ...
   struct   rilevamenti* next;
} rilevamenti_t;

void push (rilevamenti_t ** head, char id[], char nome[], char codice[], float quant, char data[]);


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    FILE *fp;
    char    tmpIdStazione[4];
    char    tmpNomeParametro[200];
    char    tmpCodiceParametro[6];
    float   tmpQuantita;
    char    tmpData[8];


    fp = fopen("file1.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL) 
    {
    perror("Error in opening file1.txt");
    return(-1);
    }

    rilevamenti_t * lista1 = NULL;


   while(1){

           fscanf(fp, "%s", tmpIdStazione);
           printf("Stazione: %s\n", tmpIdStazione );
           ...

           push (lista1, tmpIdStazione, ...);

        if( feof(fp) ) { 
         break ;
      }
   }
    fclose(fp); 

    return 0;
}


void push(rilevamenti_t ** head, char id[], char nome[], char codice[], float quant, char data[]) 
{
    rilevamenti_t * new_rilevamento;
    new_rilevamento = (rilevamenti_t *)malloc(sizeof(rilevamenti_t));

    strncpy(new_rilevamento->idStazione, id, 4);
    ...
    *head = new_rilevamento;
}
```

I think I'm missing something in the call of the push fuction,
my idead was to pass the head pointer of the list as pointer, 
so I can add all the list structures one by one from the head of the list, just changing the first pointer.

But I'm struck, I'm honestly a little rusty with C after a lot of java and C# :/

I set the "..." just to make the code shorter now, there I list all the structure's members and fill them one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the address of `rilevamenti_t*` in this case `&lista1`. It will be

```
push (&lista1, tmpIdStazione, ...);
```

Before you had a type mismatch. And  you were passing a single pointer(`rilevamenti_t *`) where double pointer(`rilevamenti_t**`) is expected. That resulted in Undefined Behavior.(You were dereferencing `NULL`).

<sub>Don't cast the return value of `malloc` and do check the return value of `malloc`.</sub>